# How to pass dynamic strings to pydantic fields

Tags: python, pydantic

I have this code in my framework on Python 3.10 + Pydantic

```
class DataInclude(BaseModel):
    currencyAccount: Literal["CNY счет", "AMD счет", "RUB счет", "USD счет", "EUR счет", "GBP счет", "CHF счет"]
```

I want to learn how to do it right to use dynamic parameters in a string

```
name = (CNY, AMD, RUB, USD, EUR, GBP, CHF)
class DataInclude(BaseModel):
        currencyAccount: Literal[f"{name}счет"]
```

With the help of regex I couldn't either

Comment: You can't. `typing.Literal` is **literal** for a reason. There is no dynamic way to specify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment already, you cannot dynamically specify a [`typing.Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) type.

Instead of doing that, you could just create your own [`enum.Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) to represent the valid currency options. Pydantic [plays nicely](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#enums-and-choices) with those. And the `Enum` [functional API](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#functional-api) allows you to set it up dynamically.

```py
from enum import Enum

from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError


CURRENCIES = (
    "CNY",
    "AMD",
    "RUB",
    "USD",
    "EUR",
    "GBP",
    "CHF",
)

Currency = Enum(
    "Currency",
    ((curr, f"{curr} счет") for curr in CURRENCIES),
    type=str,
)


class Data(BaseModel):
    currency: Currency


if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = Data(currency="CNY счет")
    print(obj, "\n")
    try:
        Data(currency="foo")
    except ValidationError as e:
        print(e)
```

Output:

```
currency=<Currency.CNY: 'CNY счет'> 

1 validation error for Data
currency
  value is not a valid enumeration member ...
```

The drawback to the Enum functional API is that your average static type checker will not be able to infer any enumeration members. Thus, your IDE will probably not provide you with auto-suggestions, if you wanted to use a member like `Currency.AMD` for example. If that bothers you, consider using the regular class definition for that `Currency` enum.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain or share link 
I would like to understand the arguments when creating an Enum

Whats is first argument "Currency" and "curr" before f.str?

Comment: @Alex Sure, here is that specific [documentation link](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#functional-api); I also added it to the post. The first argument is just the name of your Enum, which is typically the class name. Then come the Enum members, which in this case I provided as an iterator of 2-tuples; each of those is interpreted as `(name, value)` of a member. The `type` parameter is to mix in the `str` class.